# How to identify if a photon comes from the sun?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, thermal-radiation, spectroscopy, sun

Is there any way to know whether a group of particles is generated from the sun rather from an artificial source?

Comment: No, seriously, you must make sure that there is no other sources between you and the Sun. According to the Maxwell equations, all charges and currents are a source of the electromagnetic field, so to get photons from the Sun you must remove/supress the other possible sources. In other words, remove the "noise". A lot of work to do.

Comment: @Vadim: Nowadays, there is a QR code.

Comment: @user21820 this may be true for the Sun, but the photons coming from other stars were made long time ago ;)

Comment: @Vadim: Exactly; so we can tell apart those from the sun and those from alien star systems. =P

Comment: @user21820 Do you slice them open and count the rings?

Comment: I would check their meme usage. If they are outdated by 8 minutes or so, they are probably from the sun. If they are outdated by anything more than that, then they came from facebook.

Comment: Is that really a different Question than "how can two photons be distinguished"?

Comment: @user21820 you mean like this? https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/3/38/Genetic_tag.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/860?cb=20161208191021&path-prefix=en

Answer (score 53):

Photons are identical particles characterized by *energy* and a *direction of propagation*.
If you see just a photon, without any other information, from these two properties, you cannot distinguish a solar photon from one coming, let's say, from a tungsten filament at a temperature of $5800\,\mbox{K}$ (the surface temperature of the Sun).

On the other hand, if you see many photons coming from the big glowing spot in the sky, you can reliably tell that they come from the Sun.

Comment: In principle same-wavelength photons are identical, and blackbodys radiate in pure black body radiation - in practice though you have information about the distribution of photons from the sun that makes it deviate from a pure black-body spectrum; e.g. from absorption in our atmosphere and things like that. So that, if you got a box and captured some sun-photons, and got another box and captured some 5800 K tungsten filament photons; their spectroscopic data will show up different

Comment: Could photon spin be used??

Comment: @JoshuaLin If you do that you are making some assumptions such as assuming there arent other filters or sources involved. If you can make these assumptions then you arent basing your decision on the photons themselves and might as well just go with the "big glowing spot" method. Its pretty reliable.

Comment: Isn't tungsten's melting point around 3,700? The conventional use of 'tungsten filaments' usually only heats them to 2,000 to 3,300 K. Seems like that should narrow it down at least a little.

Comment: @Shmuel Newmark: Not unless the tungsten filament is really close, so that the number of photons it emits is enough to measurably distort the emission curve (as shown in another answer).  But that is a statistical measurement of a great many photons, and says nothing about the source of any individual photon.

Comment: you have helicity in addition to energy and direction of propagation. It doesn't help you distinguish the sun from other sources in general

Comment: Isn't measuring a direction of propagation pretty hard, especially for a single photon? This further complicates the problem of actual experiment, unless the sun and the other source are not both exposed to the detector at the same time. But I imagine pretty impossible to distinguish the sun and a star next to/behind on the sky emitting photons having same energy arriving at the detector would be even though classically you could expect a different angle. For multiple photons, one could obtain a distribution and infer there are two sources, for single photon it would be quite impossible IMO.

Comment: @luk32 Separating photons based on their direction of propagation is exactly what camera lenses do. They work the same with single photons as with multiple photons.

Comment: @Matt They do but single photon interaction is probabilistic. I don't think for a single photon the results are very confident but I didn't run the numbers. For multiple photons sure it's easy to draw conclusions because you have a distribution, but for a single? Not really.

Comment: @luk32 If you "run the numbers" for a single photon, the probability distribution you get will be exactly the picture the camera is showing you. If you can distinguish the star from the sun in the picture, then the camera has successfully sorted their photons based on angle. If the images of the star and sun blur into each other, then photons landing in the blur have an unclear source.

Comment: @luk32 With a wide enough camera aperture, diffraction blur can be reduced arbitrarily, leaving only atmospheric blurring (the slight randomization of incoming photon angle due to turbulent air), which is in practice the limiting factor in resolving objects (i.e. distinguishing photons from A from photons from B based on incoming photon angle) in ground based visible wavelength astronomy.

Answer (score 35):

There is no physical difference between the photons emitted by the sun and those emitted by an artificial source, so there is no way you can look at a photon and know for sure what generated it. However, sunlight has specific characteristics which means that you can usually distinguish it from e.g. electric lights.

For instance, you can look at the spectrum (frequencies) of the group of photons and see if they match the spectrum of the sun. This is because any black-body radiates light at different frequencies with specific intensities depending on the temperature of the black-body. The temperature at the surface of the sun is about 6000 K, and so it radiates light with this black-body profile.

[image: Spectrum of the sun]

There is no physical principle that prevents an artificial source from perfectly emulating sunlight however, and in that case there would be no way to distinguish the two.

Answer (score 6):

For a single photon, you can only calculate a probability based on the photon's energy (and polarisation) and the sun's spectrum.

For a group of photons, you can check for properties that are inconsistent with a chaotic (natural) origin. For example, the polarisation pattern of sunlight is well known, and your group of photons can be checked against the expected distribution.

For a group of photons, you can also test for non-classical properties, i.e. for the presence of quantum light. For example, if you detect a group of photons with perfectly equal temporal spacing (i.e. anti-bunching, second order correlation function $g^{(2)}(\tau) \leq 1)$, the light source is likely to be artificial. Various tests exist for coherent light (laser light), and other quantum light properties such as squeezing, Fock states, and entanglement.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine a quantum harmonic oscillator. You transfer some energy to the oscillator, so its energy level increases by one quantum. You transfer some more energy to the oscillator and its energy level increases by another quantum. Which quantum is which? How could you even tell?

In quantum field theory, such as quantum electrodynamics, fields are Fourier-decomposed into an infinite sum of harmonic oscillators. When the field receives energy through an interaction, one of these quantum harmonic oscillators gains a unit of energy. When the field in question is the electromagnetic field, we call that unit of energy, that unit excitation a "photon".

These unit excitations have no identity. You cannot tell which one is which. I was inclined to say that when you capture a strong beam of sunlight, chances are most of the photons you capture came from the Sun but even that is not true: it would presume that the photons in question did have an identity in secret. (Perhaps a more apt analogy would be warming a cup of water by a degree then by another degree, and then asking which degree came from where.)

Another relevant example, I think, comes in the form of solar neutrinos. Fusion reactions deep inside the Sun produce electron neutrinos. However, due to neutrino mass mixing, excitations of the neutrino fields that began their existence as electron neutrinos may be captured by a terrestrial detector as muon neutrinos. So where did a specific neutrino come from? The Sun? It didn't even emit muon neutrinos. Somewhere else? No, there are no other sources of neutrinos. Again, the answer is that just like photons, neutrinos have no identity either. What the detector interacts with is the neutrino field in its excited state, not some specific miniature cannonball fired by the Sun.

Comment: Given that the neutrino field was excited by the sun, and that the energy of this excitation travelled in a localized way from the sun to the earth, I think de Broglie would say it travelled pretty much exactly like a miniature cannonball. The fact that neutrino cannonballs have an oscillating flavor makes them pretty, but no less particle-like.